# Loop en referencia a objetos en entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

tengo una relación que es así:
Una venta tiene un negocio (el negocio donde se hizo la venta)

Luego tengo la entidad negocio por si sola, no se relaciona con ventas.

Ahora bien, me hicieron un cambio en el proyecto, y tengo que listar los Negocios con sus ventas, entonces lo que hice fue a la entidad negocio incluirle una colección de ventas.

Lo que sucede es que al ejecutarlo, el negocio busca sus ventas, y a su vez esa venta, busca un negocio, y asi tengo un loop y me da error
(Self referencing loop detected with type)

Ahora bien, hay alguna forma de decirle a la entidad Negocio que cuando vaya a buscar sus ventas, no se traiga el negocio (ya que ya lo tiene porque es el mismo)
Espero se haya entendido , estoy usando Entity Framework 6 con Anotations  y Code First. Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrias decirme en qué framework estás trabajando? ASP.NET? por ejemplo

Comment: Si, el framework  4.6

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza este ejemplo que he creado para que veas cómo puedes hacer lo que necesitas

```
public class Negocio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo Nombre es obligatorio")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Venta> Ventas { get; set; }
}

public class Venta
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Producto { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    public double Saldo { get; set; }
    public int NegocioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Negocio Negocio { get; set; }
}
```

ahora en tu controlador Negocios en la acción Index debes cambiar la consulta para que EF tome los datos de las ventas de cada negocio.

```
 // GET: Negocios
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var negocios = await _context.Negocio.Include(n => n.Ventas).ToListAsync();
        return View(negocios);
    }
```

y en tu vista debes recorrer las ventas de cada negocio para mostrarlas ejemplo:

```
 @model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.Negocio>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ventas)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
                </td>
                <td>
                    //Aqui recorres las ventas de cada Negocio para mostrarlas
                    @foreach(var venta in item.Ventas)
                    {
                        <p>@venta.Producto</p>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Este ejemplo lo he realizado en Asp.Net core pero la idea es la misma, puedes emplearla en otro proyecto. Espero te sea de utilidad

Comment: Claro, es que asi lo tengo yo, tengo una vista donde listo los negocios y ahi es donde me da el loop.
Fijate que con el codigo este, cuando lilsto los negocios, cuando ese negocio lista sus ventas, el entity ve que tiene un negocio dentro y la va a buscar, que a su vez este negocio tiene ventas, esas ventas tienen un negocio, asi sigue el lup y no me compila, se entiende?